# django: taking user input from html, processing it and showing output in the same page

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-database

I am quite new in Django and stuck at specific point. I want to take user input from html that goes into database, process it with specific python script and return result to the same html page.

I want Users to enter score in "exam_score" line, then process that input with specific python script and then to output result to "uni_name_1_result". For now, python script that just prints 'Hello world' is enough, just want to understand the mythology of how it can be done.

Would appreciate any help.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254,unique=True)
    exam_score = models.FloatField(null=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0),MaxValueValidator(700)])
    uni_name_1 = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    uni_name_1_result = models.CharField(max_length=254)
```

**forms.py**

```
  from django import forms
    from django.core import validators
    from ielts_app.models import User
    
    class NewUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
        # validations can be set here
    
        class Meta():
            model = User
            fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# from ielts_app import forms
from ielts_app.forms import NewUserForm
# from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def index(request):
    return render(request,'ielts_app/index.html')

def users(request):
    form = NewUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            variable:form.cleaned_data
            form.save(commit=True)   # to save forum data (user data), commit=True to database
            # return HttpResponseRedirect('/THANKS/')
            return index(request)  # return back to homeage after getting user data
        else:
            print("ERROR!")
    return render(request,'ielts_app/users.html',{'form':form})
```

**users.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Users</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Please Sign Up:</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="POST">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Submit">
      </form>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following way.

```
from django import forms
    from django.core import validators
    from ielts_app.models import User
    
    class NewUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
        # validations can be set here
    
        class Meta():
            model = User
            fields = ('exam_score',)
```

And in your user.html do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Users</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 

     </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Please Sign Up:</h1>
        <div class="container">
          <form method="POST">
            {% for field in form %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
             {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Submit">
          </form>
    
        </div>
    
      </body>
    </html>
```

It is better you rename your model to some other model name as it may collide with User Model given by django.

Comment: hi, thanks for comments. it is giving me error: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: tqdk_app_unisurvey.email. 

and I still not sure how can I take that user input from 'exam_score', processing it with another python script in backend and then return the result to the same html.